# VS2005 - Call a method from a separate project? (Same solution)

Tags: visual-studio

I'm having an issue calling a method from a separate project within the same solution in VS2005.  Am I just being dumb or am I missing something here?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "having an issue"?  Usually it <ProjectName>.<Class>.<Method>, like:

BusinessLayer.Employee e = new Employee("Bob");
e.TerminateAndEscortHome();

Comment: Right, it's just not working for me :(

Comment: can you add more detail. Are you referencing the project you are calling from correctly

Comment: What language are we talking about? C++? C#? VB? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added a reference to the separate project to your current project?

Answer (score 1):

Also check your access modifiers.  The class containing the method you're trying to call needs to be declared `public`.

If you don't specify an access modifier the class defaults to `internal` which means it's only accessible to code in the same assembly.

(I'm assuming C#)